# R: Update a Specific Variable in multiple R scripts

Tags: r

For some reason, my work requires me to update a certain variable in multiple R files on a daily basis (for demonstration, I use  `date.updated` as the variable name).

I am wondering if there is any way that I can automate this process:

1. **Open and Locate** the line `date.updated = as.Date('XXXX-01-01')`
2. **Change the line** to `date.updated = as.Date('XXXX-01-02')`
3. Save the R file under the same name and directory

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `date.updated` supposed to be today's date? If so, you could simply use `date.updated = Sys.date()`.

Comment: Since we do not update strictly every day, for some days, we still need `date.updated` remain as a previous date.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a basic `.R` file with only one line to be replaced:

```r
some(code)
date.updated = as.Date('2020-01-01')
date.updated = as.Date('2020/01/01')
list.files()
```

On a shell (e.g., `bash`), one can use `sed -i -E "..." file.R` to change all matching lines *in-place*. This is analogous to `sed -E "..." < file.R > newfile.R`. (Some file-systems don't do well with `-i`, so you might need the second option anyway.)

Using that, I'll demonstrate *without* replacing the file, for expediency.

```sh
$ sed -E "s/^(date\.updated\s*=\s*as\.Date)\('[-0-9]{10}'\)\s*$/\1('2020-01-02')/g" 62537920.R
some(code)
date.updated = as.Date('2020-01-02')
date.updated = as.Date('2020/01/01')
list.files()
```

If you want it to be changed programmatically to *today's date*, you can use

```sh
$ sed -E "s/^(date\.updated\s*=\s*as\.Date)\('[-0-9]{10}'\)\s*$/\1('$(date +%Y-%m-%d)')/g" 62537920.R
some(code)
date.updated = as.Date('2020-06-23')
date.updated = as.Date('2020/01/01')
list.files()
```

(I included a second `date.updated` line purely to demonstrate the specificity of the pattern.)

R typically has access to `sed` (either natively on unix/macos or via Rtools on windows), though on Windows you might need to specify its full path. If you really want to do this from R, then you can use `system`, `system2`, or `processx::run`.